When reading a csv file with Spark.read, the data is not loading in the appropriate column while passing schema
I am trying to read a csv file from storage location using spark.read function. Also, i am explicitly passing the schema to the function. However, the data is not loading in proper column of the dataframe. Following are the code details:
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType, DoubleType

# Define the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField('TRANSACTION', StringType(), True),
    StructField('FROM', StringType(), True),
    StructField('TO', StringType(), True),
    StructField('DA_RATE', DateType(), True),
    StructField('CURNCY_F', StringType(), True),
    StructField('CURNCY_T', StringType(), True)
])

# Read the CSV file with the specified schema
df = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("delimiter", "|") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .load("abfss://xyz@abc.dfs.core.windows.net/my/2024-04-10/abc_2*.csv")

**Data in the csv file**

DA_RATE|CURNCY_F|CURNCY_T
2024-02-26|AAA|MMM
2024-02-26|AAA|NNN
2024-02-26|BBB|YYY
2024-02-26|CCC|KKK
2024-02-27|DDD|SSS


Output I am getting

TRANSACTION FROM    TO   DA_RATE    CURNCY_F CURNCY_T
2024-02-26  AAA     MMM  null   null     null 
2024-02-26  AAA     NNN  null   null     null
2024-02-26  BBB     YYY  null   null     null
2024-02-26  CCC     KKK  null   null     null

**Output I am expected**

TRANSACTION  FROM    TO      DA_RATE    CURNCY_F   CURNCY_T
null         null   null    2024-02-26   AAA         MMM    
null         null   null    2024-02-26   AAA         NNN    
null         null   null    2024-02-26   BBB         YYY    


The problem is your order of the schema fields.
Just change your code to this:

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType, DoubleType

# Define the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField('DA_RATE', DateType(), True),
    StructField('CURNCY_F', StringType(), True),
    StructField('CURNCY_T', StringType(), True),
    StructField('TRANSACTION', StringType(), True),
    StructField('FROM', StringType(), True),
    StructField('TO', StringType(), True),
    
])

# Read the CSV file with the specified schema
df = (
    spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .schema(schema)
    .load("abfss://xyz@abc.dfs.core.windows.net/my/2024-04-10/abc_2*.csv")
)


If you don't want to give the correct order just use the following function. It gives you also the correct order of the schema fields.

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType, DoubleType
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def apply_schema_to_dataframe(df: DataFrame, schema: StructType) -> DataFrame:
    field_names = []
    for field in schema.fields:
        field_names.append(field.name)
        if field.name not in df.columns:
            df = df.withColumn(field.name, f.lit(None).cast(field.dataType))
        else:
            df = df.withColumn(field.name, f.col(field.name).cast(field.dataType))
    return df.select(*field_names)

# Define the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField('TRANSACTION', StringType(), True),
    StructField('FROM', StringType(), True),
    StructField('TO', StringType(), True),
    StructField('DA_RATE', DateType(), True),
    StructField('CURNCY_F', StringType(), True),
    StructField('CURNCY_T', StringType(), True)
])

# Read the CSV file with the specified schema
df = (
    spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    #.schema(schema)
    .load("abfss://xyz@abc.dfs.core.windows.net/my/2024-04-10/abc_2*.csv")
)

df_new = apply_schema_to_dataframe(df=df, schema=schema)


Also please use pharantesis instead of backslashes as it is recommend by pep ;)

Thanks for the response. I will check at my end

Do you mind upvote my answer and mark it as accepted?
